# Can't change datetime value in Razor server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I can't change datetime value because i bind the value and if I fill the whole datetime value my given value setting to be default. Sum: I want to change the value in form but i think the binding override my change in that moment.

My razor page frontend code:

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Description" class="control-label">Leírás</label>
                <input form="Description" class="form-control" @bind="@task.Description" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Duration" class="control-label">Időtartam</label>
                <input form="Duration" class="form-control" @bind="@task.Duration" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Parent" class="control-label">Szülő</label>
                <select @bind="task.ParentId" class="form-control">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    @foreach (var t in Tasks)
                    {
                        if (t.Description != task.Description)
                        {
                            <option value="@t.Id">
                                @t.Id - @t.Description
                            </option>
                        }
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Starttime" class="control-label">Kezdési idő</label>
                <input form="Starttime" class="form-control" type="datetime-local" @bind-value="@task.Starttime"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My model:

```
 public class ScheduleTask : IOid
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required, StringLength(100)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Duration { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Starttime { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Finishtime { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Previoustask> Beforetasks { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Previoustask> Previoustasks { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Taskhrdetail> Taskhrdetails { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Taskordetail> Taskordetails { get; set; }
    }
```

Every binding working good, only the starttime is unchangable for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code:

```
<input form="Starttime" class="form-control" type="datetime-local" @value="@task.Starttime"
                       @onchange="@((ChangeEventArgs __e) => task.Starttime =DateTime.Parse( __e?.Value?.ToString()))" />
```

If the input value is changed,the value will be binded to `task.Starttime`.